# php count images not all rows only image

Tags: php

I want to count the number of images, but not all rows.
This is my function:

```
function profile_count_image($user_id) {
    global $Connection;

    $sql_query = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT image FROM posts WHERE added_by='$user_id'"); 
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql_query);

    return $num_rows;   
}
```

This is what I have in the database:

[image: dsadsadsad]

And echo (return) show me: 5 ??? (Correct is 1 but show 5)

Comment: You have 5 rows with added_by = 1. Since your query has a `where added_by ..`, it's going to match the given value (which happens to repeat 5x)

Comment: I think he meant image field not blank.

Comment: @StephanSutter I'm explaining the problem, not giving the solution. There are already 3 answer trying to do that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT image FROM posts WHERE added_by='$user_id' AND image !=''");
```

Comment: Great but let me tell you that if a field is blank, you should set it to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Add a predicate to your query which checks that the image field is not null:

```
Select image from posts where added_by='$user_id' and image is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($Connection, "SELECT image FROM posts WHERE added_by='$user_id'");
```

To:

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($Connection, " SELECT image FROM posts WHERE added_by = '$user_id' AND image IS NOT NULL ");
```